# Google Compute startup script - gcloud command not found

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

In my startup script I am getting errors that the gcloud command is not found. However, if I ssh into the instance and run the command it works. I have also tried adding `/snap/bin` to the PATH with the same result.

This is running on the ubuntu-1804-lts image

```
Mar 20 20:23:47 test-ember-6b25977 startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /startup-p0mox6kf/tmp3cjjalo_: line 82: gcloud: command not found
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I found this in the logs

```
Mar 20 20:23:33 test-ember-6b25977 kernel: [   41.985708] audit: type=1400 audit(1553113413.186:44): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.google-cloud-sdk.gcloud" pid=2935 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

I just tested using the command as the first thing in the startup script and it works, then if I wait 30 seconds it will then work again. But for some time in between the command does not work.

Comment: I found a public issue opened, but just related with the 16.04 image: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904904 ..so you can run 'dpkg -l | grep '\(gce\|goog\)' and check if the guest environment(GE) version, I remember a issue like this, it was fixed with an update GE --> https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment

Comment: That appears to be unrelated, as the startup script does run, it is just the the gcloud command is unavailable for a certain amount of time close to when it starts running the startup script

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the gcloud components still starting when you run the gcloud command with your startup-script.

Did you tried to add a [sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(command)) before the gcloud command?

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is exactly what I stated in my question, it works for maybe the first 10 seconds of the startup script, then for about 30 seconds it doesn't work, so I did put a sleep in to wait

Comment: Could you provide the start-up script without sharing sensitive data?